# Analysis of Individuals using Stacked Data

Tags: r

I am a novice R user working on a Metropolis-Hastings algorithm to estimate a mixed-effects location and scale model for which software is limited.

The data I have is longitudinal and in stacked format. Example code of what this looks like for three participants is presented below. Note that the five time points are balanced for the sake of this example, but time will inevitably be unbalanced (i.e., missing and treated as continuous) when using real data. This fact precludes using multivariate/wide (i.e., GLM) format.

```
N = 3 #number of people
PersonID = c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3)
Time = c(0,1,2,3,4,0,1,2,3,4,0,1,2,3,4)
Y = c(15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29)
df = data.frame(PersonID,Time,Y)
```

I'm currently trying to estimate the likelihood of the data using the current and candidate random intercept for each person (U0i). This is done by evaluating each participant's data individually. Before I begin estimating those likelihoods, though, I want to start small and gain an understanding of what R requires, so...

I am simply trying to estimate an individual linear regression model on each participant's data. Starting here will give me an idea of what the code needs to look like to get R to work with individual participant data when the data is stacked format. I have tried so many iterations of what I thought would be correct, but here is my latest failure,

```
for (person in 1:N){
    if (PersonID == person){
        summary(lm(df$Y ~ df$Time))
    }
}
```

which gives me the error below:

```
1: In if (PersonID == person) { :
    the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

Obviously, the IF statement doesn't like that my data is stacked, with >1 row per participant. I need the data to remain in stacked format. Oh, I have tried IFELSE with no success, but I probably junked up that code. Any ideas are most appreciated.

Thanks!

Ryan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably more commonly done with an `lapply`. Observe

```
results <- lapply(1:N, function(p) {
   summary(lm(Y~Time, df, subset=PersonID==p))
})
```

basically the lapply will loop over the personIDs 1,2,...,N. You could also specify `unique(df$PersonID)` instead if they are not sequential integers. Then we perform a regression for each person, just subsetting the data for that particular person ID. This stores the results in a list. So if we wanted the first person's result, we could do

```
results[[1]]
```

and if we wanted to see the coefficients for all models, we could do

```
lapply(results, coef)
```